# When exactly are Qt Quick items repainted?

Tags: qt, graphics, qml, qtquick2, repaint

When exactly are Qt Quick items repainted? I.e. on which events?

For example, if I have overlapping items A and B, and I change a property of A, will B get repainted as well? If not, how can it work?

What if they are non-overlapping?

Comment: Have a good read of https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html

Comment: @peppe: Ok, thanks. What I read so far (part of the 1st link) seems to say that only when `QQuickItem::update()` is called is anything repainted, and moreover, when that method is called, all the items in the window are repainted (which however doesn't mean that all the data is necessarily re-transferred to the GPU).